# передача в java команды через Php

Tags: php, javascript

доброе время суток, коллеги!

мне нужно вывести в список на web-странице фамилии сотрудников в зависимости от должности. 
при выборе должности из списка запускается скрипт 
очищает список и начинает заполнять заново

```js
  theinput = document.getElementById(theinput);  
  var idx = thelist.selectedIndex;
  var content = thelist.options[idx].innerHTML;
  theinput.value = content;
 
  theclear=document.getElementById(theclear); 
  theclear.innerHTML = '';

  var elem=document.createElement("option");  
  elem.innerText="Выберите сотрудника";
  theclear.appendChild(elem);
  theclear.firstChild.nodeValue="Выберите сотрудника";
```

дальше идет вставка на php
подключение к базе данных, передача параметров, выборка данных
которые нужно отобразить в списке

для чего я задаю цикл

```
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res))
{
    echo "elem=document.createElement('option') ";
    echo "elem.innerText=".$row['naim']." ";
    echo "theclear.appendChild(elem)";
}
```

но данные не обновляются
хотя сообщения об ошибках не выдает

хотя, если вношу тестовые данные вручную, все работает корректно.
вопрос: как мне расставить кавычки в коде, чтобы java принял мою команду?

заранее спасибо

Comment: 1. Java и JavaScript - разные вещи. 2. JavaScript вылодняется в браузере, а php - на сервере.

Comment: я изменяю цикл вот так                                                                              'while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res))
 {
  echo "elem=document.createElement('option'); ";
  /*echo "elem.innerText=".$res['naim']."; ";*/
  echo "theclear.appendChild(elem);";
 }'                                                 и мне выводит соответствующее количество элементов списка. но без фамилий

Comment: Вы запутались. Чтобы вывести опции select - javascript вообще не нужен.